# Scala-cats: reader-composition

Tags: scala, scala-cats, for-comprehension, reader-monad

```
import cats.data.ReaderT
import cats.instances.either._

trait Service1
trait Service2
case class Cats(name:String)

type FailFast[A] = Either[List[String], A]
type Env = (Service1, Service2, Cats)
type ReaderEnvFF[A] = ReaderT[FailFast, Env, A]

def toReaderEnvFF[A](input:A):ReaderEnvFF[A] =
  ReaderT((_:Env) => Right(input))

def c:ReaderEnvFF[Cats] =
  for {
    cats <- toReaderEnvFF((_:Env)._3)
  } yield cats   // This line is 26
```

Error:

> Error:(26, 11) type mismatch;  found   : T1.this.Env =>
>   com.savdev.Cats
>       (which expands to)  ((com.savdev.Service1, com.savdev.Service2, com.savdev.Cats)) => com.savdev.Cats  required: com.savdev.Cats   }
>   yield cats

Can you please explain, why cats is not `com.savdev.Cats`? And why in the error, it says that it is expanded to a function with return method `[Cats]`, bot not `FailFast[Cats]`

I try to apply exactly the same logic as here:

```
trait Service1 { def s1f = Option(10) }
trait Service2 {
  type ReaderS1[A] = ReaderT[Option,Service1,A]
  import cats.syntax.applicative._
  import cats.instances.option._
  def s2f:ReaderS1[Int] =
    for {
      r2 <- ReaderT((_: Service1).s1f)
      r1 <- 1.pure[ReaderS1]
    } yield r1 + r2
}
```

In this example I could convert function Service1.s1f to its result r2 and it works fine. Why I cannot, for instance write something like:

```
for {
 cats <- ReaderT((_:Env)._3)
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toReaderEnvFF((_: Env)._3)` in `cats <- toReaderEnvFF((_: Env)._3)` is actually `toReaderEnvFF[A]((_: Env)._3)` for some type `A`. What is `A` now? Since `(_: Env)._3` (aka `input` in `toReaderEnvFF`) is of type `Env => Cats` then type `A` is `Env => Cats`. So `toReaderEnvFF((_: Env)._3)` is of type `ReaderEnvFF[Env => Cats]` and `cats` in `cats <- toReaderEnvFF((_: Env)._3)` is of type `Env => Cats`.

In `x <- SomeMonad[T]` variable `x` is of type `T` (now `SomeMonad` is `ReaderEnvFF`, `T` is `Env => Cats`).

`ReaderT((_: Service1).s1f)` in your second example is of type `ReaderT[Option, Service1, Int]` so `r2` in `r2 <- ReaderT((_: Service1).s1f)` is of type `Int`. But in your first example `toReaderEnvFF((_: Env)._3)` is of type `ReaderEnvFF[Env => Cats]` aka `ReaderT[FailFast, Env, Env => Cats]` so `cats` in `cats <- toReaderEnvFF((_: Env)._3)` is of type `Env => Cats`. That's the difference.

If you want to work with `ReaderEnvFF[Cats]` then you should change `cats <- toReaderEnvFF(???)`. For example

```
def c:ReaderEnvFF[Cats] =
  for {
    cats <- toReaderEnvFF(Cats("aaa"))
  } yield cats
```

Comment: but can I get cats from a depedency? Cause Cats is part of Env

Comment: @Alexandr Get from where? If you have `ReaderEnvFF[Env]` (for example with `Kleisli#tap`) you can get `ReaderEnvFF[Cats]` (with `Kleisli#map(..)`) .

Comment: you know, it still not clear. In the `r2 <- ReaderT((_: Service1).s1f)` type of  `r2` is Int, but in the same/similar expression:   `cats <- ReaderT((_:Env)._3)` cats is of type `Env => Cats`. For me syntax is the same. I still cannot see a difference. Attributes of ReaderT cannot affect it right? Can you please explain this in another words.

Comment: @Alexandr `(_: Service1).s1f` is of type `Service1 => Option[Int]`, so `ReaderT((_: Service1).s1f)` is of type `ReaderT[Option,Service1,Int]`, so `r2` in `r2 <- ReaderT((_: Service1).s1f)` is of type `Int`.
`(_:Env)._3` is of type `Env => Cats`, so `ReaderT((_:Env)._3)` is of type `ReaderT[Id,Env,Cats]`, so `cats` in `cats <- ReaderT((_:Env)._3)` is of type `Cats`.

Comment: @Alexandr It's not about syntax, it's about types.